# How to add ip as a variable to pxe cfg file

Tags: rhel, variable, pxe

I am installing my linux OS using PXE  and I want to automate my process using variables or files. I need to know how can I import the ip address from another file and add it as a parameter to pxe ksnew.cfg file.
For example, if I have this nfs command:

```
nfs --server=10.0.0.110
```

in ksnew.cfg file, I want to replace it with:

```
nfs --server=$ip
```

and import $ip from other file (I have many servers and they have use different Ips).

Is there a way to do this that? Is there another method that solve my problem ?

Thanks

Comment: where's this from? Kickstart? PXE menus? Could you explain further what you're trying to do?

Comment: yes it is Kickstart file. it is located in /tftpboot/RH/ksnew.cfg directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed  -i "/nfs/s/=.*//g" ksnew.cfg file ;while read line; do  sed "s/$/='$line'/g" ksnew.cfg file ; done <Inputfile_consists_of_ip's
```

ksnew.cfg file===> Configuration file

Inputfile_consists_of_ip’s===> File consists of list of IPS

Inputfile_consists_of_ip’s Consists below content

```
10.10.10.11

11.1.1.2

3.3.3.5
```

So output will be

```
nfs --server==10.10.10.11

nfs --server==11.1.1.2

nfs --server==3.3.3.5
```

Comment: Can I use sed or linux command inside kickstart configuration file (cfg file) ??? is linux terminal existed while installing time?

Comment: Could you explain further why you rejected my edit to this post to repair the formatting?

Comment: @grgarside sorry it was by mistake

Comment: @jaadsalem Yes You can use sed command in Config file.                                  If you want to execute particular script on every boot  mention script in /etc/rc.local  so it will execute on every boot

Answer (score 0):

My kickstart is a little rusty, although you should be able to embed some shell scripts creating files, which could then be processed by your kickstart.

Let's assume the following snippet:

```
%include /tmp/pre_network
firewall --disabled
%include /tmp/install_url

[ ... ]

%pre
#!/bin/sh
exec </dev/tty8 >/dev/tty8
chvt 8
#set the following vars with whatever logic applies in your case, ...
REMOTENFS=10.2.3.4
REMOTEPROXY=10.2.5.4
#//
echo "network --bootproto=dhcp --hostname=pxe.localdomain --noipv6" >/tmp/pre_network
if test "$REMOTENFS"; then
    echo "nfs --server $REMOTENFS" >/tmp/pre_network
elif test "$REMOTEPROXY"; then
    echo "url --url=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/ --proxy=http://$REMOTE_PROXY:3128
else
    echo "url --url=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/
fi >/tmp/install_url
clear
chvt 1
%end

[ ... ]
```

Eventually, you would edit the `%pre` so it would look for your local IP, domain name pushed by DHCP, `curl` a webservice or whatever, ... deducing your nfs server remote.

And since you ask about running sed commands from a kickstart, note you could also script stuff to be run finishing your install:

```
%post
#!/bin/sh
exec </dev/tty8 >/dev/tty8
chvt 8
sed -i 's|.*|myhostname|' /mnt/sysimage/etc/hostname
chvt 1
%end
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. I will try to use %post and update :)

Comment: unfortunately the method didn't work. I should use only a static ip with nfs command or server hostname. any ideas how can I configure the same name to different ips?